# How to strip out month/year/date from input string given to moment javascript irrespective of local timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to strip out just month year and date from an input string passed into moment javascript.

```
Ex: dateString = moment(2019-12-15T08:00:00.000Z)
month = dateString.month()
year = dateString.year()
day = dateString.date()
```

What is happening is the input is converted depending upon local timezone where the code is run.

How can I ensure that the local timezone is not considered in the input and only month/year/day values are stripped out?

Comment: Split the dateString by 'T' and use moment.format()
`moment.utc('2019-12-15T08:00:00.000Z'.split('T')[0]).format('M/D/YYYY')`

Answer (score 0):

Split the dateString by 'T' and use moment.format()

```
moment.utc('2019-12-15T08:00:00.000Z'.split('T')[0]).format('M/D/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

Input value always like this, you can split many times and get the date.

```
dateString = moment(2019-12-15T08:00:00.000Z);
time = dateString.split("T"); // time[0] = 2019-12-15 , time[1] = 08:00:00.000Z
date = time[0].split("-"); // date[0] = 2019 , date[1] = 12 , date[2] = 15
year = date[0]; // 2019
month = date[1]; // 12
day = date[2]; // 15
```

Or use that

```
var dt = new Date( "December 25, 1995 23:15:00" );
month = dt.getMonth();
```